# How to modify working regex in PCRE2 but failing in Ruby (invalid conditional pattern)

Tags: regex, ruby, conditional-operator, pcre2

I've this regex:

```
^([A-Z]{2,}\!?) ([^(]+)(?<!\s) ?(?<BR>\()?((?(BR)[^\)]+))(?(BR)(\)))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/NiMbut/1

to validate input strings that follow these rules:

```
PREFIX description goes here (optional)
```

1. PREFIX word required (all upcase, optional last char !);
2. "description goes here" required;
3. optional value in parentheses.

The regex has to fail if string doesn't follow correct syntax.
Description submatch has to remove trailing spaces after description if there's optional value). Optional value submatch is without parentheses.

It perfectly works in PCRE2 php but fails in Ruby, but Idk why.

Comment: Can you give a few examples especially cases in which the regex fails but should pass?

Comment: I solved, thank you. In ruby, the conditional operator `(?(BR)(\))` requires the brackets: `(?(<BR>)(\))`.

Comment: Your conditional operators are useless, all you have to do is to put all the subpattern in an optional group: https://regex101.com/r/Uhqs99/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte great!

Comment: See this [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) for more information about conditionals, including references to Ruby.